# Package keyval Error: breakaftergroup undefined

Tags: minted

I have this cryptic error message, and I am not sure what to do. The MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}

\usepackage{minted}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline, BCOR = 5mm, DIV = 17}

\newmintinline[cpp]{cpp}{breaklines, breakafter = :\(\)<>, breakaftergroup}

\begin{document}
\cpp{fmt::print("Hello World!\n");}
\end{document}
```

When compiling it results in

```
/home/user/mwe/mwe.tex:16: Package keyval Error: breakaftergroup undefined.
```

`breakaftergroup` is described in the documentation, and it is also defined in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty`:

```
\minted@def@optfv@switch{breakaftergroup}
```

Comment: I've also created an [issue on Github](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/358)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `minted` sets up `breakaftergroup` to be an option forwarded to `fvextra`. But `fvextra` doesn't have a `breakaftergroup` option since version 1.5 (released on 2022-11-30) anymore.

You can instead set up an option for `minted` that'll call the new replacement option, that is `breakafterinrun`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}

\usepackage{minted}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline, BCOR = 5mm, DIV = 17}

\makeatletter
\minted@def@optfv@switch{breakafterinrun}
\makeatother

\newmintinline[cpp]{cpp}{breaklines, breakafter = :\(\)<>, breakafterinrun}

\begin{document}
\cpp{fmt::print("Hello World!\n");}
\end{document}
```